# JDBC Domain Design and Relationships

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I've used Hibernate / JPA in the past, now using a combination of Spring JDBC and MyBatis.

With JPA/ Hibernate if you had a Customer, which had an address you would have a domain structure similar to code below. (minus all the annotations / config / mappings).

Does this still make sense when using JDBC or MyBatis. This is composition domain design from what I know, has-a, belongs-to, etc. However most examples I've seen of JDBC code they have domain object that bring back the IDs rather than collection, or flatten the data. Are there any performance benefits from either approach, maintainability, etc. Having worked with JPA first I'm not sure what the JDBC way of doing things are.

```
public class Customer {

    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Collection<Address> addresses
    ...
}

public class Address {
    private Long id;
    private String streetAddress1;
    private String streetAddress2;
    private String city;
    private State state;
    private String postalCode;
}

public class State {
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private Country country;
}

public class Country {
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
}
```

I come across an example and here was one of their classes.

```
public class Question {
    private long questionId;
    private long categoryId;
    private long userId;
    private long areaId;
    private String question;
    private String verifyKey;
    private Date created;
    private User user;
    private List<Answer> answers;
    private long answerCount;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters omited...
}
```

Why would you fetch the userId, areaId, and categoryId instead of actually fetching the associated object? The ID is likely of no use to the front end user, I suppose you could use the ID to issue another query to fetch additional data, but seems inefficient making another round trip to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this domain object as a "footprint" of database table. In your example, *userId*, *areaId* and *categoryId* from `Question` are most likely foreign keys from corresponding tables. You could never need full object data in the moment of Question creation and retrieve it later with separate db request. If you fetch all associated objects at once, you will hit at least one additional table per object (by join-s or subselect-s). Moreover, that's actually the same that Hibernate does. By default, it loads domain object lazily and hits database again if uninitialized associated object is needed.

At that time, it is better to fetch those objects that a domain object can't exist without. In your example, Question and List are coupled.

Of course, if you need user, or category, or any other associated object again in some another place of application (assume the reference to previously retrieved object has been lost), you will hit the database with same query. It should be done and could seem inefficient, because both plain JDBC and SpringJDBC have no intermediate caching unlike Hibernate. But that's not the purpose JDBC was designed for.

Comment: What do you mean by "You can look at this domain object as a "footprint" of database table"? If I am understanding you correctly the domain doesn't have be a 1 to 1 with the database, but should be similar. As an example the Address object, it really doesn't make sense for it to exist without a State, thus instead of stateId it should reference the State object?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean Question domain object, but `Question` class in the first statement.
What about Address and State, that depends on their typical usage in your application. Is State object used via Address object in most cases? If no, then what's a need to initialize it?
Of course, you can insist on _State_ field instead of _stateId_ and leave it as `null`. But personally I wouldn't do so. It confuses developers who expect a State object to be initialized and also requires null checks all over the code.

Comment: What about the n+1 problem, say I need to return 100 addresses to the UI, and it needs to display the state name, not the Id, now you run one query to get all the address rows, and issue another query per row to get the state for a total of 101 queries, is that acceptable to do for JDBC? The more sub collections you have the collect the much worse it gets

Comment: You can join address table with state table in one query for each address. The result set, for example, could contain _addressId_, _street_, _houseNumber_, _stateId_, _stateName_, _stateAbbreviation_. Columns related to state are mapped to State object. Those related to address are mapped to Address object itself and so on.